# sidenotes package: horizontal spacing after the sidenote mark

Tags: spacing, sidenotes

If I use the package sidenotes and try the following:

```
Test\sidenote{Side note.}, continue.
```

there is a big space before the comma.

Is it possible to avoid this?

Comment: You should report this at https://github.com/andythomas/TeX-sidenotes/issues or write an email to Andy Thomas.

Comment: In the meantime you could try the [`snotez`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/snotez) package as an alternative... :)

Comment: https://github.com/andythomas/TeX-sidenotes/issues/28 tracked and closed by Andy Thomas. Maybe its already corrected for the next version.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi the fix has been four months ago but obviously v0.93 did not make it to CTAN, yet... I still believe it would be best to contact Andy.

Comment: Thank you all! I have installed the last version from the github!

Comment: I apologize for the recent laziness in upgrading the CTAN repositories. I promise improvement :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to cgnieder for picking up on some missing `%` signs.  But even with that fixed, it still added too much space for my taste.  So I removed a few spaces.  I checked, and it does NOT seem to misspace things when getting into double digits, so you might be good to go.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\makeatletter
\renewcommandtwoopt{\sidenote}[3][][]{%
\sidenotemark[#1]%
\sidenotetext[#1][#2]{#3}%
\@ifnextchar\sidenote{\kern-0.07em\textsuperscript{,}}%
{\@ifnextchar\sidecite{\kern-0.07em\textsuperscript{,}}{}}% <<SPACE REMOVED
}
\renewcommandtwoopt{\sidenotetext}[3][][]{%
\ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}{% sitenotemark given?
\addtocounter{sidenote}{-1}%
\ifthenelse{\isempty{#2}}% offset given?
{\marginpar{\textsuperscript{\thesidenote}{}#3}}% <<<SPACE REMOVED
{\marginnote{\textsuperscript{\thesidenote}{}#3}[#2]}% <<<SPACE REMOVED
\addtocounter{sidenote}{1}}%
{\ifthenelse{\isempty{#2}}% offset given?
{\marginpar{\textsuperscript{#1}#3}}% <<<SPACE REMOVED
{\marginnote{\textsuperscript{#1}#3}[#2]}}% <<<SPACE REMOVED
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Test\sidenote{Side note.}, continue.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There's a spurious space at the end of the redefinition of `\sidenotetext`

Comment: @cgnieder  Don't know how I missed that (also wrong in original package).  Will fix.